# Any PDF readers that can read an XAF form

Tags: pdf, livecycle, xfa

Any readers besides Adobe Acrobat and Reader that will allow me to fill out and save dynamic XAF form created with LiveCycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic XFA forms are rather proprietary. There may be some viewers available, mainly from the greater SAP environment (which licensed Adobe's technology).

On iDevices, Readdle claims that PDFExpert can handle XFA files, but it may be just static forms.

Comment: I figured that none of them could handle dynamic forms.